# Is it possible to have a phone without a voice plan?

Tags: voip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I receive phone calls through WiFi on an Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/8449/how-can-i-receive-phone-calls-through-wifi-on-an-android-phone)

I have an unlocked Nexus One.  I barely use the voice function, mostly just use data.  However, I'd like to have the voice function just in case.

Is it possible to use something else (possibly VOIPish) to replace the voice plan that I am currently paying?  Perhaps Skype, or Google Voice or something else.  Has anyone had an experience with this?

Thanks

Comment: Not exact duplicate; as linked answer assumes presence of WiFi. This question is about *data*; which is what you use when you are not near WiFi.

Answer (score 2):

Since the cell network was originally built for voice, the cell companies kind of have a focus on voice. While this might be technologically possible, I can't imagine how you'd convince a cell phone company to sell you a data-only plan for a device that supports voice. I'm not sure it makes business sense for them to do so - after all, why not rip you for at least a little voice, along with the data. If you don't use it much, then so much the better because they save on capacity.

Comment: It's on T-Mobile right now and they have no problem selling me a data only plan.  I think this might be because the phone is unlocked and not on contract.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable to expect phone companies to offer data-only plans. Modern phones have so much technological potential, but US phone carriers avoid innovation wherever possible. Their stagnant, short-sighted attitude drives me crazy.

Answer (score 2):

You could buy a plan for a data card (T-Mobile sells PCMCIA cards that pick up a wireless signal, or maybe a 3G iPad plan with AT&T) and swap the SIM card out. Haven't heard any stories about this, but I don't see why it wouldn't work.

AFAIK, Google Voice doesn't support VOIP.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really an option unless you're deaf or hard-of-hearing, but there are plans like this that do exist. On AT&T, it's called the [Text Accessibility Plan (TAP)](http://www.wireless.att.com/learn/articles-resources/disability-resources/text-accessibility-plan-for-iphone.jsp) <sup>1</sup>, and it offers you unlimited messaging/data while still having calls at 40¢ per minute.

<sub>1. These plans are not exclusive to the iPhone; I don't know why it lists those phones as the only options.</sub>