# How can I receive phone calls through Wi-Fi on an Android phone?

Tags: wi-fi, voip

How can I receive phone calls from a landlines/cellphone when I have Wi-Fi connectivity, but no cell phone service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could signup for [Skype](http://www.skype.com) and get a Skype "[Online Number](http://www.skype.com/intl/en/features/allfeatures/online-number/)" (this used to be called "Skype In") and then install the [Skype app](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.skype.raider) on your phone.

This would give you a real phone number that anyone could ring from a normal landline or mobile, that would ring through to Skype on your phone (or any other device) over your data connection.

Comment: I used Skype app to keep in touch with the UK while in India, it worked really well.

Answer (score 3):

T-Mobile US has a Wi-Fi Calling app available, and other carriers might have done the same.  There might be charge for some of these services, but when I was on T-Mobile it was free.

Answer (score 2):

Yes if you use a VoIP app and your cellphone service provider lets you divert your number on no connection - but remember that you will bear the cost for the diversion.

If you want to just have a wifi-based (VoIP) number that's separate from your cell number then any VoIP service provider will be able to do that - I have a test VoIP setup on my HTC Desire in the UK that lets anyone call my mobile on an 0845 number.

Answer (score 2):

I you can get a free or paid SIP account and use something like SIPDroid.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that [Viber](http://www.viber.com/) will do just that, if you're calling other people with Viber.

Answer (score 1):

If your friends don't have viber you can use a [MobileVoip](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=finarea.MobileVoip)
The list of voip provider supported is endless: http://www.mobilevoip.com/en/supported_brands